# Why Doesn't This Using Declaration on a `template` Class's Enum Work?

Tags: c++, enums, scope

This compiles:

```
template <typename T> class Parent { public:
  enum MyEnum { RED,GREEN,BLUE };
};
class Child : public Parent<int> { public:
  using Parent<int>::MyEnum;
  int foo() { return GREEN; }
};
void tester() { Child d; d.foo(); }
```

This doesn't (on gcc, this outputs `error: 'GREEN' was not declared in this scope`):

```
template <typename T> class Parent { public:
  enum MyEnum { RED,GREEN,BLUE };
};
template <typename T> class Child : public Parent<T> { public:
  using Parent<T>::MyEnum;
  int foo() { return GREEN; }
};
void tester() { Child<int> d; d.foo(); }
```

**My question: why?**  (Also, any suggestions for a workaround?)

Comment: Two-phase name lookup. `GREEN` is not a dependent name, and is looked up at the point of definition of `foo`, before `Child<int>` and `Parent<int>` are instantiated. To make it a dependent name (and thus defer the lookup to the point of instantiation), you'll have to write `Child::GREEN` or `Parent::GREEN` or `this->GREEN`.

Comment: (c++11) `enum class` may be useful here, to avoid regular enum's behavior of automatically exposing the constants in the enclosing scope, which imo causes a lot of confusion in situations like this...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what about something like `int foo(Parent<T>::MyEnum e) { return e; }`?

Comment: What about it? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second code :

1. You need to add the typename keyword because you access the type MyEnum is dependent on T. Change the line of the using to this :

`using typename Parent<T>::MyEnum;`

2. Then, in the method `foo` you need to specify that GREEN is a member of the enum MyEnum like that :

`int foo() { return MyEnum::GREEN; }`

compiled fine for me with gcc and clang with C++11
Live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0893a9ed0beef6d3)

It worked in the first example because MyEnum in the line of the using is not dependent of a template type T. You used explicitly Parent with type int.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
using Parent<int>::MyEnum;
```

has no bearing on being able to use `GREEN` in the line

```
int foo() { return GREEN; }
```

You can remove the first line and the second line should continue to work.

As for the second example, you can use:

```
template <typename T> class Child : public Parent<T>
{
    public:
      using Parent<T>::GREEN;
      int foo() { return GREEN; }
};
```

It's not immediately clear to me why `Parent<T>::GREEN` is not automatically available in `Child`

Comment: `It's not immediately clear to me why Parent<T>::GREEN is not automatically available in Child` Like I said, [two-phase name lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html)